# Can't Parse Up One Directory Command in PHPUnit Testing with PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I have PHPUnit set up in my PHPStorm project.  I've referenced the PHPUnit phar file and have a PHP executable linked to my PHPStorm run configuration.  My directory structure looks like:

```
/lib/classes/Class.php
/lib/vendor/phpunit.phar
/lib/test/ClassTest.php
```

In my `ClassTest.php` file, I reference the other two files with:

```
require_once (__DIR__ . "../vendor/phpunit.phar");
require_once (__DIR__ . "../classes/Class.php");
```

I get the following error when I run my test:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
'C:\Users\me\PhpstormProjects\myproject\lib\tests../vendor/phpunit.phar'
```

It seems like the PHP parser isn't correctly parsing the up one directory `../` command.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does the path need to be like `tests/../vendor` instead of `tests../vendor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all:** this line is not needed (at all) as PHPUnit will already be loaded at that time.

```
require_once (__DIR__ . "../vendor/phpunit.phar");
```

---

**Secondly:** `__DIR__` constant in PHP does not contain trailing slash. When used in require/include statements (and other places when building full file path) you have to add it yourself.

In your particular case it has to be (note `/` before `..`):

```
require_once (__DIR__ . "/../classes/Class.php");
```